# Want AutoIt3 HotKeySet to Emulate AutoHotKey Application Filtering

Tags: autohotkey, autoit

**Objective**

I am building a generic solution for advanced controlling of an arbitrary programs UI using AutoIt3, invoked by pressing various keys, or issuing a command.

**Components**

- TargetUI - Program to be controlled by sending clicks and keys
- MainAu3 - AutoIt program doing the sending
- MainIni - File containing control positions and other info in a specialized notation, also contains hotkey information. All info is specific to a particular TargetUI - ie. One MainIni for each TargetUI
- KeyHookScript - optional? Either AutoIt or AutoHotKey script

**Facts**

- HotKeySet() - AutoIt function allows setting and unsetting of **system-wide** hotkeys
- AutoHotKey - Scripting Language - Allows Application filtering for hotkeys via `#IfWinActive`
- MainAu3 is currently designed to take a command param, provided by some KeyHookScript
- MainAu3 is slow to invoke, due to parsing of MainIni on startup, which is necc. due to program goals

**Issues**

- Since MainAu3 is slow to invoke, one option is to have it run in the background and have its own keyhooks, OR have the KeyHookScript communicate with it somehow
- MainAu3 and MainIni will have more than one instance -- an instance for each TargetUI. This causes collision if using `HotKeySet()` in each MainAu3 unless you set and unset everytime TargetUIs get focus - which seems to be asking for trouble

**Anticipated Approach**

- It looks like I will need a MainAu3Manager that monitors applications and ensures the proper MainAu3/MainIni are running as needed. It will also need to maintain the Singleton(?) KeyHookScript written in AutoHotKey

**Questions**

- How ill-advised is it to attempt to swap out HotKeySet/Unset via each MainAu3 based on application that has focus and is a TargetUI?
- Given that is a bad approach, which communication method is best to talk to the running MainAu3s?
- How hard is it to create my own hooking mechanism in AutoIt via `_IsPressed`, and would that create a "polling problem" if it is running frequently in each MainAu3

**Communication Methods**

These are all the ones I can think of and I want this to be fast and reliable, and easily coded haha

- File based - create a file(s) in some directory containing the command, let MainAu3 delete it/them
- Registry - probably slower than files
- Hidden window - Communicate by setting window text (I KNOW!) faster than file?
- Hidden window - `SendMessage` ugh, too hard to code
- DDE - don't get me started

**Decision Point**

I will need to communicate with a running MainAu3 regardless, because, reasons. The real issue is whether to embed the keyhook mechanism inside MainAu3 instances or not.

What I would like is if AutoIt had a reliable mechanism for keyhooks that were application specific like in AutoHotKeys `#IfWinActive`.

If I embed, I hate both options of setting and unsetting `HotKeySet()`, as well as polling `_IsPressed()`. Then again, an external keyhook via AutoHotKey is a pain too.

I think I will try embedding with `HotKeySet()` first, and see how that acts.

Any advice?

**Note**
"Communication" is one-way - I just need to send commands.

Comment: What about asking one question at a time?

Comment: _IsPressed is not reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the GUI you are trying to control is your own GUI:

If you want hotkeys that are not system wide, you should use

> GUISetAccelerators ( accelerators [, winhandle] )

```
GUISetAccelerators

Sets the accelerator table to be used in a GUI window.
```

Parameters

```
accelerators    A 2 dimensional array holding the accelerator table (See remarks).
winhandle   [optional] Windows handle as returned by GUICreate() (default is the previously used window).
```

Remarks

```
The array passed to this function contains the hotkey and the control ID of the accelerator. The array must be defined as Local/Global $aArray[n][2] - where n is the number of accelerator keys to set:

    $aArray[0][0] = Hotkey (in HotKeySet() format) of 1st accelerator
    $aArray[0][1] = Control ID of the 1st accelerator, as returned by GUICtrlCreate...
    $aArray[1][0] = Hotkey of 2nd accelerator
    $aArray[1][1] = Control ID of the 2nd accelerator
    ...
    $aArray[n][0] = Hotkey of nth accelerator
    $aArray[n][1] = Control ID of the nth accelerator

Passing this function a non-array will unset all accelerators for the given winhandle.
```

Example:

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Example()

Func Example()
    GUICreate("Custom MsgBox", 225, 80)

    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Please select a button.", 10, 10)
    Local $idYes = GUICtrlCreateButton("Yes", 10, 50, 65, 25)
    Local $idNo = GUICtrlCreateButton("No", 80, 50, 65, 25)
    Local $idExit = GUICtrlCreateButton("Exit", 150, 50, 65, 25)

    ; Set GUIAccelerators for the button controlIDs, these being Ctrl + y and Ctrl + n
    Local $aAccelKeys[2][2] = [["^y", $idYes],["^n", $idNo]]
    GUISetAccelerators($aAccelKeys)

    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW) ; Display the GUI.

    While 1
        Switch GUIGetMsg()
            Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
                MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "You selected", "Close")
                ExitLoop

            Case $idYes
                MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "You selected", "Yes") ; Displays if the button was selected or the hotkey combination Ctrl + y was pressed.

            Case $idNo
                MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "You selected", "No") ; Displays if the button was selected or the hotkey combination Ctrl + n was pressed.

            Case $idExit
                MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "You selected", "Exit")
                ExitLoop

        EndSwitch
    WEnd
    GUIDelete() ; Delete the GUI.
EndFunc   ;==>Example
```

If you are controlling an external GUI then maybe try fiddling with [Any GUI](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/9517-anyguiau3/) to make it work